# How to get JButton default background color?

Tags: colors, background, default, jbutton

I use this `myButton.setBackground(myColor)` to change the `JButton` background color to my color, how to find it's original default background color so I can change it back? I know I can save its default background color before I change and use that, but I wonder if Java stores it somewhere so that maybe I can call something like: `myButton.getClass.getDefaultBackground()` to get it back ?

Answer (score 14):

`btn.setBackground(new JButton().getBackground());`

how about this...
it will get the default color of button

Comment: This works and probably has pretty negligible overhead. I like it.

Answer (score 10):

```
myButton.setBackground(null)
```

changes it back to the default color.

Comment: This changes it to null color, not default.

Answer (score 3):

This might help:

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/SystemColor.html

```
Toolkit.getDesktopProperty(java.lang.String)
Toolkit.getDesktopProperty("control");
// control - The color rendered for the background of control panels and control objects, such as pushbuttons.
```

Answer (score 1):

It works both with:

```
button.setBackground(null);
```

and

```
button.setBackground(new JButton().getBackground());
```

(*when you create a new **JButton**, its background color is initialized as a **null** color*) 
So, choose the one you consider to be the best for your project

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to get background from Jframe or other elements to apply it on the button; if you already changed it do this:

```
ElementToStyle.setBackground(null);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, I edited your answer to make clarify your answer (still your content) and remove the insults. It's not a huge deal but it makes this site better as a whole. Again, welcome to StackOverflow and thank you for taking time to share your knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

1. make a new button "db"
2. make a new variable type Color "jbb"
3. i.e. -     Color jbb = db.getBackground();

now the default background color is stored in the Color jbb which you can now use as the color you want to find/use

Answer (score 0):

```
   Color cbt= jButton6.getBackground();

        String color_button=cbt.getRed()+","+cbt.getGreen()+","+cbt.getBlue();
```

if you wont get RGB color button
try this code