# How do I reach the SystemColors in Netbeans 7.4?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, colors, systemcolors

I'm trying to set a JButton's background color back to its default color, "Control". Where can I find that color? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it

```
   myButton.setBackground(null)
```

it change back to the default color.

may be possible answer here

[How to get JButton default background color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358398/how-to-get-jbutton-default-background-color)