# Set Background Color Temporarily on Button

Tags: java, android

Does anybody know how to set the background color temporarily on a Button.

```
buttons[randomI][randomJ].setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(155, 17, 30));
```

Here is what I have but I only want to set the background color of this for a certain period of time. I understand that a way to go about this is to remove the background color after a certain period of time but I don't know how to remove background color. I referenced: [How to get JButton default background color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358398/how-to-get-jbutton-default-background-color) and the solutions did not work for me.

In the top answer:

```
btn.setBackground(new JButton().getBackground());
```

JButton does not exist for me and using new Button().getBackground says that it can not resolve constructor. So is there any way to temporarily set the background color?

Answer (score 0):

Store the previous color of the `Button`:

```
int color = 0; // Black default
Drawable drawable = buttons[randomI][randomJ].getBackground();
if (drawable instanceof ColorDrawable) {
    color = ((ColorDrawable) drawable).getColor();
}
```

Set the new color temporarily:

```
buttons[randomI][randomJ].setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(155, 17, 30));
```

and after some period restore the initial color:

```
buttons[randomI][randomJ].setBackgroundColor(color);
```